# images aren't displayed on the admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models, django-1.6

I'm following the django page which explains how to display images https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

And I think that I did all what's specified such as:

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django.contrib.staticfiles',)
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/my_app/")

def image_tag(self):
    if self.image:
         return u'<img src="{0}" />'.format("/" + self.image.url)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

admin.py

```
list_display = ('description', 'image_tag',)
```

But my image is not showing up.
What am I missing?

Comment: you have to prefix image's path with `MEDIA_URL`: use `settings.MEDIA_URL + self.image.url` as an image path

Comment: note: uploaded images are considered as a **media files**, not **static files**